# Como copiar datos de la hoja de respuestas del formulario a otra hoja de calculo o adicional enviar las respuestas directamente a otra hoja de calculo

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Buen día, espero alguien pueda ayudarme con mi duda, soy nuevo en esto de hojas de cálculo de Google y empiezo a automatizar alguna cosas. 
Tengo un script que valida las respuestas de un formulario, mi problema es que no he podido copiar datos de la hoja de respuestas del formulario a otra hoja de calculo o enviar directamente las respuestas del formulario a otra hoja de calculo.

Comparto el script detallado y de antemano agradezco su valiosa ayuda.

Valido las respuestas al enviarse el formulario y le asigno un numero consecutivo;

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {

var Consecutivo = AgregarNumeroConsecutivo();

var timestamp =e.values[0];
var Contrasena =e.values[1];
var Autoriza =e.values[2];
```

Las respuesta 2 y 0 las envío a la celda G1 en la hoja de respuestas del formulario.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh =  ss.getSheets()[0];
var sheet =ss.getSheets()[0];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() 
[0].getRange("G1:G1").setValue(Autoriza+"\n\n"+timestamp);
```

Después intento copiar la celda G1 a otro libro; no he podido hacer funcionar este paso.

```
var target = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1osnF08ciK8b0jnYpWwOi9uahv7LxVh4We1hyFXapo-k");
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Vale de salida");
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("G1:G1");
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("B5:B5");

source_range.copyTo(target_range);
}
```

Función para agregar numero consecutivo a respuesta de formulario.

```
function AgregarNumeroConsecutivo() {
var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fila =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var Consecutivo = fila -1;
hoja.getRange(fila,4).setValue(Consecutivo);
return Consecutivo;

}
```

Comment: Mencionas que no has podido hacer funcionar un paso ¿Obtienes algún mensaje bde error?

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolver mi problema que plantee con la pregunta inicial.
Use algo sencillo.

Elimine esta parte del código.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh =  ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet =ss.getSheets()[0];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() 
  [0].getRange("G1:G1").setValue(Autoriza+"\n\n"+timestamp);
  var target = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1osnF08ciK8b0jnYpWwOi9uahv7LxVh4We1hyFXapo-");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Vale de salida");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("G1:G1");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("B5:B5");

  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  }
```

Como solo necesitaba 2 respuestas y el rango destino siempre seria el mismo, lo sustituí por esta linea. ahora cada ves que responden un formulario, las respuesta se va a la hoja predeterminada de respuestas y adicionalmente 2 respuestas se van a otra de hoja de calculo.

```
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("1osnF08ciK8b0jnYpWwOi9uahv7LxVh4We1hyFXapo-").getSheets()[0].getRange("B22").setValue(Autoriza+"\n\n"+timestamp);
```

Asi quedo mi script final.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {

var Consecutivo = AgregarNumeroConsecutivo();

var timestamp =e.values[0];
var Contrasena =e.values[1];
var Autoriza =e.values[2];

SpreadsheetApp.openById("1osnF08ciK8b0jnYpWwOi9uahv7LxVh4We1hyFXapo- 
").getSheets()[0].getRange("B22").setValue(Autoriza+"\n\n"+timestamp);
}


function AgregarNumeroConsecutivo() {
var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fila =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var Consecutivo = fila -1;
hoja.getRange(fila,4).setValue(Consecutivo);
return Consecutivo;

}
```

Comment: Por si acaso no lo sabías, puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta. Ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer